# Display one object property value, and show another one on hover

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-multiselect

the question I have might be hard to understand, so please help me re-organize the question if you can see the better way to put it in.

So, I am building a registration platform.

(1) First, I receive an array of objects of cases the user can sign time to.

[image]

(2) Each object consists of 2 properties, "name", "description".

[image]

(3) I store the array in the data, end use it in the element provided by a picker called **"vue-multiselect"**, which basically accepts the array and loops over the objects and displays them.

[image]

[image]

(4) As you can see, it displays both properties and values, which I am trying to avoid. **My question** is, is it possible to pass only the **"name"** value into the picker, and display the **description** value when hovering the first value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this use case documentation here: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-custom-option-template

```html
<multiselect v-model="value" 
             deselect-label=""
             select-label="" 
             placeholder="" 
             selected-label="" 
             :show-pointer="true"
             :options="projectCases">

    <template slot="option" slot-scope="{ option }">
        <strong :title="option.description">{{ option.name }}</strong>
    </template>
</multiselect>
```

ps: I use title attribute to implement display-on-hover functionality. you can use any other tooltip library as well.

Comment: This is a great solution, but it only shows the description once the item is selected, but it doesn't work while the dropdown menu is open.

Comment: Figured it out by adding a custom function provided in "Custom option template". Thanks for the help

Comment: You are right. Just have to change the slot to `option`. Answer edited. Thank you